# Object Model List all users with full control on a sub site in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, development, permissions, object-model

If I have a sub site URL and a user with Site Admin, can I list all users in that sub site that have Full Control at that level?

Any C# code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following C# code:

```
using(SPWeb web = SPSite(webUrl).OpenWeb())

 {

 SPRoleDefinitionCollection roleDefinitions = web.RoleDefinitions;

 SPRoleDefinition roleDefinition = roleDefinitions["Full Control"];



 foreach (SPRoleAssignment roleAssigment in web.RoleAssignments)

 {

 if (roleAssigment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Contains(roleDefinition))

 {

 SPPrincipal oPrincipal = roleAssigment.Member;//it can be SPUser or SPGroup, you can process and add it to the result

 }

 }

 }
```

OR you can use:

```
bool userhasPermissions = web.DoesUserHavePermissions(user.LoginName, SPBasePermissions.FullMask);
```

For getting in Powershell use:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5884.sharepoint-2010-get-site-users-with-full-controlowners-permissions-with-powershell-script.aspx